# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data - NodeJS vueJS

Tags: json, node.js, vue.js, syntax-error

Estou usando uma aplicação com vuejs e node, e preciso pegar informações através de um .json, mas ao fazer a requisição obtenho o seguinte erro:

*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data*

O meu Json está correto, segue o código:

```
getCars(){

        fetch('../data/carros.json')
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
        }
    },

    mounted(){
       this.getCars();
}
```